# Merge two BST into Red Black Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I have the following problem :

Given two binary search trees T1 ,T2 with  m and n nodes and h1 and h2 heights.

How I can merge those trees into red black tree with tome complexity `Θ(max(m,n))`
and space complexity `Θ(max(h1,h2))`?

Thanks

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. What is the actual question or problem?

Comment: yes, it's a homework , the actual question is as described. I know how to do it with Θ(m+n)) complexity (by creating sorted array from both trees). But need some hint how to do it with described space complexity .

Comment: Please fix your question: Are T1 and T2 rb trees? Also you are using Theta not Omega. Much harder to calculate. But why not just take the smaller tree and insert it into the larger one element at a time? What's the Theta of that?

Comment: They are not rb trees, I need to merge them into rb tree.

Comment: I don't believe it can be done with the requirements that the two trees are simply BST. First you need to make a RB of the larger. And then move the items from the smaller to the larger. The space complexity is easy it's the computation I don't think can be /achieved.